# How to get a number from Excel in scientific notation as long?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have this scientific notation number  which states for

Scientific Notation Number is stored in a Excel sheet and I need to convert 2.97112E+13 to its original number. I tried both of them not working:

```
int val = new BigDecimal().intValue();
ouput  -1383753728
```

And

```
String val = new BigDecimal("2.97112E+13").toPlainString();
output  29711200000000
```

Here's my code:

```
 Workbook workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(SAMPLE_XLSX_FILE_PATH));
            int trys=0;
     Boolean flag=true;
        // 1. You can obtain a sheetIterator and iterate over it
        Iterator<Sheet> sheetIterator = workbook.sheetIterator();

        while (sheetIterator.hasNext()) {
            Sheet sheet = sheetIterator.next();
           // System.out.println("=> " + sheet.getSheetName());
        }
        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        String cellValue=" ";
        // Create a DataFormatter to format and get each cell's value as String
        DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter();

        // 1. You can obtain a rowIterator and columnIterator and iterate over them
     //   System.out.println("\n\nIterating over Rows and Columns using Iterator\n");
        Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sheet.rowIterator();
        while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
            Row row = rowIterator.next();

            // Now let's iterate over the columns of the current row
            Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

            while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {

                Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

               Boolean h=true;

              String  cellValue = dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
```

here cellValue is the String which stores the value of the cell

Comment: 2.97112E+13 is not the same as 29711202104111.

Comment: `29711202104111` doesn't fit in an `int` but in a `long`.

Comment: how it can be converted to long ?

Comment: Please edit your question and show us: 1) how you're opening the Excel file, 2) how you're reading the value from the cell.

Comment: Why are you reading everything as String rather than properly analyzing each cell? Anyway, here's an answer that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10857718/1065197 (disclaimer: it's my answer).

Comment: working man thanks could you add this to an answer to accept it

Comment: It's ok, you can upvote my answer when you have enough rep.

Comment: Thanks Very much i really  needed that answer Fast Thanks